# R. lapply multinomial test to list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, multinomial

I have a data frame `A`, which I split into a list of 100 data frames, each having 3 rows (In my real data each data frame has 500 rows). Here I show A with 2 elements of the list (row1-row3; row4-row6):

```
A <- data.frame(n = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2),
                prob = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1),
                count = c(24878, 33605, 12100 , 25899, 34777, 13765))

# This is the list:
nest <- split(A, rep(1:2, each = 3))
```

I want to apply the multinomial test to each of these data frames and extract the p-value of each test. So far I have done this:

```
library(EMT)

fun <- function(x){
  multinomial.test(x$count,
                   prob=x$prob,
                   useChisq = FALSE, MonteCarlo = TRUE,
                   ntrial = 100, # n of withdrawals accomplished
                   atOnce=100)
}

lapply(nest, fun)
```

However, I get:

```
 "Error in multinomial.test(x$counts_set, prob = x$norm_genome, useChisq = F,  : 
   Observations have to be stored in a vector, e.g.  'observed <- c(5,2,1)'"
```

Does anyone have a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: I don't get an error when I run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of `split` are created with names `1`, `2` and so on. That's why `x$count` in `fun` cannot access it. To make it simpler, you can combine your splitted elements using the `list` function and then use `lapply`:

```
n <- c(0,1,2,0,1,2)
prob <- c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1)
count <- c(24878, 33605, 12100 , 25899, 34777, 13765)
A <- cbind.data.frame(n, prob, count)

nest = split(A,rep(1:2,each=3))

fun <- function(x){
  multinomial.test(x$count,
                   prob=x$prob,
                   useChisq = F, MonteCarlo = TRUE,
                   ntrial = 100, # n of withdrawals accomplished
                   atOnce=100)
}

# Create a list of splitted elements
new_list <- list(nest$`1`, nest$`2`)

lapply(new_list, fun)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with dplyr.

```
A = data.frame(n = c(0,1,2,0,1,2),
               prob = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1),
               count = c(43, 42, 9, 74, 82, 9))

library(dplyr)
nest <- A %>%
  mutate(pattern = rep(1:2,each=3)) %>%
  group_by(pattern) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(mn_pvals = multinomial.test(count, prob)$p.value)
nest
```

Comment: Hi @paoloeusebi, your solution also works great, but Vishesh's posted a solution first. Thanks very much

Comment: The most important things are that you have two solutions and I have learned something new.

Comment: Glad to hear that !